# SendMessage not working with InternetExplorer object

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, sendmessage, user32, shdocvw

I am trying to simulate mouse left click for InternetExplorer object, even when the IE object is a background window. The system function I am using is SendMessage. Below is relevant code.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

InternetExplorer IE = new InternetExplorer();
IntPtr handle = (IntPtr) IE.HWND;

int x = 50;
int y = 50;
IntPtr lParam = (IntPtr)((y << 16) | x); // X and Y coordinates of the click
IntPtr wParam = IntPtr.Zero;

const uint downCode = 0x0201; 
const uint upCode = 0x202;
SendMessage(handle, downCode, wParam, lParam); // mousedown
SendMessage(handle, upCode, wParam, lParam); // mouseup
```

I know for sure that the position I specified will generate a new IE window upon left click. However, that doesn't happen using the code above. So, what am I missing here?

**update**
The OS is Windows 7 Professional. The IDE is Visual Studio 2013 Pro.

I also tried adding a manifest and specifying UIAccess="true" per [this page](http://nsylvain.blogspot.com/2008/01/integrity-drop-or-how-to-disable-uipi.html). But it didn't work.

Comment: FYI there are better ways to invoke clicks on elements (via the DOM) if that's your intent

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I will certainly try out the DOM approach. However, in the meantime, I still would like to understand why SendMessage is not working.

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3443518/932282 and also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7121314/932282

Comment: What I don't see here is how you are setting the mouse position. If your intention is to have hovering over something click where previous it would merely hover, then this approach works fine. If not, you need your mouse pointer in position before this will click on what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simulate mouse events with postmessage/sendmessage, because the mouse up/down events are always send at the **current** cursor position. You could first set the mouse position, but that won't work when the window is in the background or minimized.

More information: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3443518/932282), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13654714/932282) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7121314/932282).